Docker container requires rebuild for every change in server.js despite using volumes
I’m working on a Node.js backend project, and I’m using Docker with Docker Compose for my setup. My folder structure looks like this:
project-root/
│
├── server/
│   ├── Controllers/
│   ├── db/
│   ├── node_modules/
│   ├── Routers/
│   ├── server.js
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── package.json
│   └── package-lock.json
├── docker-compose.yml
└── Client/

Despite using volumes in my docker-compose.yml to map my local server folder to the container, every time I make a change in server.js, I need to rebuild the Docker container for the changes to take effect. My expectation is that changes should be immediately reflected in the running container without a rebuild, especially since I’m using nodemon to watch for file changes.
docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    command: npm start


Dockerfile
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]


Package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  }
}

I want changes in my server.js file (and others) to be automatically picked up by the container without needing to rebuild. How can I achieve this? Is there something wrong with my volume setup, or am I missing something else?

Why force Docker into this workflow?  Can you use plain Node, without involving a container at all?

@DavidMaze I'm using Docker because this setup is part of a larger project where the entire environment (database, frontend, backend) is containerized. Docker provides consistency across different machines, and it helps ensure that all developers and deployment environments have the same configuration.

You should be able to run docker compose up -d database backend to start the external dependencies, and then use a host-based Node environment for actual development and debugging.  Your development environment shouldn't need to be an exact replica of production, and it seems unlikely your code depends on an exact patch level of the Node interpreter.

Have you checked if everything is copied to the container? And what happens in the container when you save a file?

this all looks correct. But I'd swap out the volume binding and replace it with compose watch which can copy the files or trigger rebuilds as required.

I’m not sure if I implemented this correctly, but I modified my script to use
“start”: “nodemon --legacy-watch server.js” 

and it seems to be working! Now, I don't have to rebuild my Docker container whenever I make changes to my code.
